# Trouble figuring out GROUP BY behaviour in this specific query

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have two tables: CUSTOMERS(CustNo, Cname, City) and ORDERS(OrderNo, Odate, CustNo, Ord_amt), where CustNo in ORDERS is a reference to the one in CUSTOMERS.

This query is giving me back "not a GROUP BY expression":

```
SELECT Cname, COUNT(*), AVG(Ord_amt)
FROM CUSTOMER NATURAL JOIN ORDERS
GROUP BY CustNo;
```

It works fine when I group by Cname or (CustNo, Cname), though.

If I add CustNo to SELECT, the same error is fired, but if I select CustNo *instead of* Cname, then `GROUP BY CustNo` works fine, and the same behaviour happens with Cname.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't use `natural join`.  Be explicit about the columns used for joining.

Second, it is best practice for the unaggregated columns in the `select` to match the `group by`:

```
SELECT c.Cname, COUNT(*), AVG(o.Ord_amt)
FROM CUSTOMER c JOIN
     ORDERS o
     USING (CustNo)
GROUP BY c.Cname
```

Comment: hello! thanks for your answer. is this best practice being enforced by the dbms?

Comment: @Luyw: By most of them. Oracle does, that's why you get the error. Exceptions to some extend are MySQL and SQLite for example.